# Uncaught type error after Wordpress update to 5.5.3 and visual composer to 6.4.1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I got some uncaught error after updating WP to 5.5.3 version and visual coomposer to 6.4.1.
Visual composer page builder stopped working, it only shows shortcode in the backend. Luckily nothing breaks on the front-end.

When logged in backend in chrome see this error in console.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined" at backend.min.js?ver=6.4.1:10.
[image: screenshot in chrome]

And when logged in firefox see this.
"Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.vcAccordion is undefined" backend.min.js:10:55131.
[image: screenshot in forefox]

I also installed Enable jQuery Migrate Helper plugin, it didn't resolve the issue.
Also installed classic editor didn't help.

Can anyone tell what could be reason here and how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to deactivate all plugin excepts visual composers. if an error did not occur then activate plugin one by one and check which plugin not compatible.

Comment: @Zain, Your problem resolve? How to resolve it? I have the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try Reset Roles and Capabilities. It`s works for me

Comment: Where to reset it?

Comment: Answer the above question!